# How do I get Active Directory group id for authorized user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, active-directory

I have web application that uses the `Authorize` attribute with roles specified to restrict access to some pages:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AD_group1, AD_group2")]
```

The question is - is there any way I can get some kind of an Active Directory `groupId` for authorized user (no matter int or string)?

**upd:**
Basic idea is to store some table in database, containing templates which should be separate for every group. e.g. users in `group1` can have some templates for fast answer to typical questions while `group2` doesn't have any of them, or have some other templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // find a user
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");
   // or if you want the currently logged in user - you can also use:
   // UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

   if(user != null)
   {
       // get all groups the user is a member of
       foreach(GroupPrincipal group in user.GetAuthorizationGroups())
       {
           string distinguishedName = group.DistinguishedName;
           Guid groupGuid = group.Guid;
       }
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I have error on production System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'? Do know what to do?